# Multiple REST requests in parallel?

Tags: rest-api, composite

Can we make request to Salesforce REST API's (i.e. insert or even composite) in parallel?

If yes, is there a total number of requests we can make in any given time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the API call lasts for more than 20 seconds, then you can do 25 such long calls at a time,
26th request will be denied with message `Concurrent API limit exceeded`.

If calls are smaller ie less time consuming then I dont see any limit on those except (Max API calls allocation for the day)

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm